# corresponding mysql version of mariadb 10.3

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, mariadb, lamp

hi to all I have some sites hosted on my local cluster but my wordpress sites plugins are showing mysql version=5.5.5 and are asking me to upgrade to mysql version at least to 5.6. The cluster has mariadb updated to latest 10.3.11 version so I was thinking that wordpress maybe is not showing things as they are or maybe I have to change in mariadb configuration something for showing the right version.
Any suggestions??
many many thanks

Comment: What plugin or plugins is pestering you to upgrade? MariaDB 10.3 should be fine for WordPress support.

Comment: the latest Reactive Search Pro is giving me this 5.5 value I cannot understand where is coming from this 5.5 version

Comment: are you sure your .ini points the db stuff to mariadb instead of a pre-installed mysql?

Comment: I don't know, how can I view this?

Comment: I have some software that says things like needs mysql 5.7 or above, and trying to find the version of mysql that mariadb uses is a pain! There needs to be a table of mariadb version to mysql version so that its easier to work out if it will be compatible.